# Web based forms for sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any "Access-like" tool for sql server and that is web based? I mean having rich controls and automatically creating web forms.

My goal is to create an offline database in SQL server. I just don't know what is the best tool to use.

Comment: Just for your use or for other users? And those users are not developers?

Comment: Question is not so clear .Do you mean managing sql server from a web inteface ? http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/ check this .

Comment: Not managing. Automatically creating forms like in access. This is for use for non-developers.

Comment: QUESTION: Is it a bad idea to use Access with SQL server? Though it is not webbased I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use access with a SQL Server backend, though this of course is not web based.

As far as I know, there is nothing that will create a CRUD web application for you.

I suggest reading and learning about [ASP.NET](http://asp.net) and [ASP.NET/MVC](http://asp.net/mvc), with either C# or VB.NET.

There are many tools that help and assist with the data access - ORM tools like [nHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateForNET) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx), but these will not create the data for you.

SQL Server also supports the [OData](http://www.odata.org/) protocol for exposing data on the web.

Comment: What is the best solution in your opinion for small database for inserting records by non-admins (50-100 tables).

Comment: @user194076 - "best" for what?

Comment: I mean what is the best solution for developers in terms of simplicity and powerfulness of the application. Like if you would have a task to create a web-based forms for sql server what tools would you use (nHibernate vs Entity Framework vs OData)

Comment: @user194076 - simplicity and powerfulness tend to be opposites. The most power would be to hand code your data access, the simplest would be to use one of the ORMs (EF looks like a very easy one to get started with).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean managing sql server from a web inteface ? http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com check this

The SQL Server Web Data Administrator enables you to easily manage your SQL Server data, wherever you are. Using its built-in features, you can do the following from Microsoft Internet Explorer or your favorite Web browser:

- Create and edit databases in SQL Server or Microsoft SQL Server Desktop Engine (MSDE)
- Perform ad-hoc queries against databases and save them to your file system
- Export and import database schema and data
- Manage users and roles
- View, create and edit stored procedures